# Angular Dynamic Forms and Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, dynamic-forms

I have built a dynamic form component in Angular 5 (based on documentation and example from https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form).

Everything works find until I try and use angular material.

I have read a number of articles here on similar issues but they all seem to be because people were not importing correct modules or using mdInput or mat-Input instead of matInput.  This is not the case for the problem I am experiencing.

Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated.

**CHANGED CODE - BREAKS with ERROR -**

*mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.***

**Dynamic Form Control Component Template**

The only change I made to the working code below is to wrap the input field in  and add the matInput attribute to the input field.

I am importing all the Material Modules (MatFormFieldModule and MatInputModule etc through a core module.  All my material Inputs and Form Fields work in all other components in the application, so i don't believe the issues is that i am missing anything in  the imports.

```
<div [formGroup]="form">

    <div [ngSwitch]="control.controlType">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="{{control.label}}" *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="control.key" [id]="control.key"
                [type]="control.type">
        </mat-form-field>
        <select [id]="control.label" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="control.key">
            <option value="">Select {{control.label}}</option>
            <option *ngFor="let opt of control.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{control.label}} is required</div>
</div>
```

**CURRENT CODE - This works perfectly but I am not getting the angular material formatting**

**Selector**

```
<mi-dynamic-form [controls]="controls"></mi-dynamic-form>
```

**Dynamic Form Component**

```
    import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { DynamicFormBase } from './dynamic-form-base';

@Component({
    selector: 'mi-control',
    templateUrl: './dynamic-form-control.component.html'
})
export class DynamicFormControlComponent {

    // API
    @Input() control: DynamicFormBase<any>;
    @Input() form: FormGroup;

    get isValid() { return this.form.controls[this.control.key].valid; }
}
```

**Dynamic Form Component Template**

```
    <div [formGroup]="form">
    <div [ngSwitch]="control.controlType">
            <input  placeholder="{{control.label}}" *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="control.key" [id]="control.key"
                [type]="control.type">
        <select [id]="control.label" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="control.key">
            <option value="">Select {{control.label}}</option>
            <option *ngFor="let opt of control.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{control.label}} is required</div>
</div>
```

**Dynamic Form Control Component**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { DynamicFormBase } from './dynamic-form-base';

@Component({
    selector: 'mi-control',
    templateUrl: './dynamic-form-control.component.html'
})
export class DynamicFormControlComponent {

    // API
    @Input() control: DynamicFormBase<any>;
    @Input() form: FormGroup;

    get isValid() { return this.form.controls[this.control.key].valid; }
}
```

**Dynamic Form Control Component Template**

```
 <div [formGroup]="form">
        <!-- <label [attr.for]="control.key">{{control.label}}</label> -->

        <div [ngSwitch]="control.controlType">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput placeholder="{{control.label}}" *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="key" [id]="control.key"
                    [type]="control.type">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-select [id]="control.label" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="control.key">
                <mat-option value="">Select {{control.label}}</mat-option>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of control.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </div>

        <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{control.label}} is required</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think your <mat-select> must be surrounded by <mat-form-field>

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but i had that in originally and took it out as i was trying to rule out if it was an error with either one of them.  Putting it back in still gives me the same error

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this working with both [Angular Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) and [Material](https://material.angular.io/). Check out working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-material) showing both Dynamic Forms and use of Material.

Comment: This was truly great for what I am doing right now

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you had solved this problem. The error of mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl. means the material components used are not imported. i.e. MatButtonModule needs to be imported when using mat-button directive.